# Перевод из n-ричной системы счисления и обратно

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Сгодится алгоритм на любом языке, как перевести, допустим, число "1000000" из десятичной системы счисления в 54-ричную, и обратно?

Comment: >Сгодится алгоритм на любом языке

было бы забавно, если бы кто-нибудь запилил на Brainfuck'e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что у вас не получается?

[Пример перевода системы счисления](http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=847)

Comment: Вот

    var k = 8, s = '9'; 

    var x = 0, len = s.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

      x = x * k + (+s[i]);

    }

    alert(x);

Comment: @Fangog, естественно, ведь девять это не правильная восьмеричная цифра.

Для каждой системы счисления у Вас д.б. свой набор (алфавит) **правильных** цифр.

Comment: Приведите ключевые выдержки по ссылке в текстовом виде в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Для РНР должен предупредить насчет base_convert() - эта функция тупо пытается представить исходник в виде числа, и, как следствие, для значений, превышающих PHP_INT_MAX, переводит его во float, со всеми вытекающими. В первую очередь это необратимая потеря значения - обратная конвертация даст другое число.
Плюс значения, полученные на 32-х и 64-х битных архитектурах различаются.

Но для некритичных задач, скажем, укорачивания некритичных же хэшей md5 в принципе годится.

Answer (score -1):

`string base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )` — Преобразование числа между произвольными системами счисления
P.S. это на `PHP`, в `JavaScript` для этих целей `parseInt`